# filter and count in a ruby array of hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, filter, aggregate

IN my ruby script, I have an array of hashes like

```
arr[{acnt=>"001"},{acnt=>"001"},{acnt=>"002"},{acnt=>"002"},{acnt=>"003"}]
```

I'd like to count the number based on each account so that the output would be like:

```
output[{"001"=>2}, {"002"=>2}, {"003"=>1}]
```

how should I do?

thanks, Jon

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have a single Hash `{'001' => 2, '002' => 2, '003' => 3}` than an array of Hashes? i.e.: `arr.each_with_object({}) {|i, o| o[i[:acnt]] = (o[i[:acnt]] || 0) + 1}`

Comment: @Myst You could do that a bit cleaner if your Hash had a default value: `arr.flat_map(&:values).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |v, h| h[v] += 1 }`.

Comment: @muistooshort  - I love it  :)

Comment: @muistooshort and Myst, thanks! Actually my original hash object has other attributes. I used "acnt" only for the sake of simplicity, so i need to specify the attribute hence Myst's way works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
arr = [{acnt: "001"},{acnt: "001"},{acnt: "002"},{acnt: "002"},{acnt: "003"}]
arr.group_by{ |g| g[:acnt]}.map{ |k, v| {k => v.count} }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** I just noticed @muistooshort's comment, in which he suggested the same thing that I have except for the (simple) final step (`map { |k,v| { k=>v } }`). μ, if you wish to post an answer, I'll delete mine.

There are many ways to do this. Here is one:

```
arr = [{ "acnt"=>"001" }, { "acnt"=>"001" }, { "acnt"=>"002" },
       { "acnt"=>"002" }, { "acnt"=>"003"}]

arr.flat_map(&:values).
    each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |s,h| h[s] += 1 }.
    map { |k,v| { k=>v } }
  #=> [{"001"=>2}, {"002"=>2}, {"003"=>1}]
```

The steps are as follows:

```
a = arr.flat_map(&:values)
  #=> ["001", "001", "002", "002", "003"] 
h = a.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |s,h| h[s] += 1 }
  #=> {"001"=>2, "002"=>2, "003"=>1} 
h.map { |k,v| { k=>v } }
  #=> [{"001"=>2}, {"002"=>2}, {"003"=>1}]
```

Comment: No worries, `flat_map` and `each_with_object` is a pretty natural way to go about this.